# Scala 2.10-M1 and 2.9 same time on Devel Machine?

Tags: scala, versions, simultaneous

**Edit:**
Got it sorted, SCALA_HOME + /bin to PATH sets the default interpreter; i.e. typing "scala" from bash prompt invokes 2.9.1 in my case. Just downloaded 2.10.0.M1.  Invoking /path/to/2.10/bin/scala from bash brings up 2.10 REPL.

I'll just add a terminal alias for 2.10 so I don't have to type out the path manually.

**Original:**
Do I need a guest VM to pull this off, or in Linux, can I somehow run 2.10 and 2.9 side-by-side?

Basically, I'd like to experiment with 2.10-M1 reflection and see what runtime havoc I can wreak on case classes while continuing with general 2.9.1 development.

If not, a Kotlin-esque web demo sure would be nice to mess around with during the 2.10 evolution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem at all with installing multiple versions of Scala; just install them in two different directories. Make sure you call the right version of `scalac`, `scala` and other executables when you want to use a specific version.

Scala does not require any system-wide settings that prevent you from having more than one version on your computer at once.

Comment: Well, at any rate, not a brilliant one. Seems obvious now.  We'll leave it intact, might help someone else with a similarly questionable question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

They will co-exist just fine. Remember that `scala` is really just a thin wrapper around Java from a runtime perspective. That is:

- you can run compiled scala using the standard `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` as long as `scala-library.jar` is on the classpath
- the REPL is contained within a scala distribution

Comment: got it sorted, was not at all thinking clearly, can run 10 versions of scala if one were so inclined

Comment: these are both right answers, just +1'd yours @oxbow (believe you got credit from another one of my SO posts so giving jesper the nod)